# What does "elastic score" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

At the sports website XtraTime.in, you can find the phrase:

> Barcelona had no difficulty in thrashing the Spanish second division Hercules 7-0 to advance to the last 16 of the King’s Cup. At home, the team secured the elastic score without Messi, Suarez and Neymar – the trio Won off on Wednesday. 
>   ([reference link](http://xtratime.in/football/copa-del-rey-barcelona-smashes-hercules-with-arda-turan-hat-trick/))

Does **elastic score** mean that the team won by a big difference?

Comment: Never heard of the usage. It might be some specialised "sports commentary" thing, but looking at the full article, I get the impression it's "creatively translated" from a different language. For example, I find it hard to see how *In the first leg of the match, the match had already **equalized** in a 1-0 lead* could be a special domain-specific usage.

Comment: 'elastic score' has no meaning in English.  I suspect this is a mistranslation from Spanish.

Comment: I'd say either of the first three comments could apply here. There's not enough context in the article to know for definite.

Comment: With only a single (highly suspect) example, I think it's "Unclear" what's being asked about here.

Comment: Actually there appear to be a definition of ***elastic soccer*** http://www.myfootballgames.co.uk/game/5/Elastic-Soccer.html

Comment: That site (http://xtratime.in/about-us/) has very messy, unedited writing. I don't think it is a translation. Elastic time should be: overtime. Apparently, this entrepreneur takes himself rather seriously and could do with some serial (joke) editing,

Comment: @Lambie: I looked at the link for about 10 seconds before posting my first comment, at which time I'd have given odds of 10:1 on it being a translation. Noting that you don't think so, I just gave it another 20 seconds, and I'd now say the odds are at least 100:1.

Comment: No time now. Gotta go. Later. :) I asked my husband, an expert (used to play pro in Spain and is Spanish): tiempo elastico? No way, he said. So, it may be a translation but not from Spanish.

Comment: Checking with  Google, it looks like "elastico" is a term used in soccer to refer to team methodology.   https://www.google.it/search?q=futbal+elastico&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT606IT607&oq=futbal+elastico+&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i65j69i60l2.6022j0j8&hl=it&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8 - http://www.allenaremania.com/2015/07/metodologia-spagnola-elastico-difensivo-errato/

Comment: @Lambie it can't be overtime - the score was 7-0.

Comment: @JOSH It's a term used in Brazilian Portuguese. But not in European Portuguese as far as I'm aware. And in PT-BR it means winning by a big difference.

Comment: @ArturCarvalho - it us used also in Italian soccer contexts. I am not an expert though.

Comment: I´m from Brazil and confirm we use this kind of expression when talking about a big difference in soccer score!

Comment: I have now done a lot of research: um placar elástico is to beat the other team with many goals or a series of goals. Or by a wide margin. To give them a thrashing.  In Portuguese: goleada. You can refer to my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And in PT-BR it means winning by a big difference.

The usages I have found in English seem to mean this too. Additionally, there are strong indications that most of the people who use this expression are Brazilian:

> Human-Genocide: I still see a BIG "we can't do it" in the eyes of Asian and African teams with big teams coming to this like if it's a shore and worth nothing, making them lose by 5 or 6 rather than a competitive 2 - 0.
>
> Annotator: It's quite rare to see any Asian or African side losing by an elastic score.
>
> <sub>[Match Thread: Guangzhou Evergrande vs Atletico Mineiro (Club World Cup 3rd place playoff)](https://www.reddit.com/r/soccer/comments/1telcb/match_thread_guangzhou_evergrande_vs_atletico/)</sub>

For that example, /u/Annotator's profile implies that they are Brazilian (because they say "in Brazil" as if they live there).

In this example, there's a pretty clear connection with Portuguese (from context, it's likely Brazilian Portuguese), since that's what the rest of the page uses:

> Nicknamed The Glorious applied by knockouts in the early twentieth century , the football team is responsible for more elastic score in the history of Brazilian football : 24x0 Sport Club on the hose .
> <sub>[BOTAFOGO FR - Ninguém Cala o Nosso Amor!!](http://173.209.59.50/index.php?topic=60314.0)</sub>

**This all points to "elastic score" being a literal translation of the (Brazilian) Portuguese idiom. But it's not idiomatic in English.**

It's far more idiomatic to call this a [blowout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowout_(sports)) instead.

Comment: Here is the term (no score though) in Portuguese: drible elástico, and here is the translation of the definition: An elastic [shot or kick] is when a player is stopped in front of the player marking him and touches the ball twice with the same foot, thereby changing the movement of the ball.  See it here: dicasdeboleiro.com.br/dicas-dribles-de-futebol/

Comment: Also: The 'Ronaldinho elastico' is a dribbling technique where the attacker fools the defender with deft footwork. :)

Comment: I found the PORTUGUESE: :) https://esporte.uol.com.br/futebol/ultimas-noticias/2016/12/21/barcelona-da-folga-ao-trio-e-avanca-na-copa-do-rei-com-gol-de-brasileiro.htm

Comment: Here is the explanation of this newish expression: 'placar elástico' é sinônimo de goleada=placar elástico is synonymous with score many goals one after another. https://esporte.uol.com.br/futebol/campeonatos/copa-do-brasil/ultimas-noticias/2012/04/10/gremio-ignora-vantagem-e-mira-placar-elastico-contra-o-ipatinga-em-casa.htm

Comment: What a funny thing. This is forum dedicated to English language and usage and here we have citations from texts that are google translated at best. Frankly, I find this literal translations shameful.

Comment: Correction: find these [above]

Answer (score 2):

The BAD English: The home, the team secured the elastic score without Messi, Suarez and Neymar – the trio Won off on Wednesday.

The GOOD Portuguese: Em casa, a equipe assegurou o placar elástico sem Messi, Suárez e Neymar - o trio ganhou folga nesta quarta-feira (21).
https://esporte.uol.com.br/futebol/ultimas-noticias/2016/12/21/barcelona-da-folga-ao-trio-e-avanca-na-copa-do-rei-com-gol-de-brasileiro.htm

The RIGHT translation: At home, the team thrashed its opponents with one goal after another without Messi, Suarez and Neymar - the trio were not playing [had the day off] this Wednesday.

Placar élastica = to thrash their opponents with a series of goals [as was the case here: 7 TO 0]

The DEFINITION in Portuguese, translated:
Pode ser que o jogador tenha se expressado mal, mas fato é que no linguajar do futebol, 'placar elástico' é sinônimo de goleada.

It may be that the player expressed himself badly, but the fact is that in football lingo, "placar elástico" is synonymous with a series of goals. 
https://esporte.uol.com.br/futebol/campeonatos/copa-do-brasil/ultimas-noticias/2012/04/10/gremio-ignora-vantagem-e-mira-placar-elastico-contra-o-ipatinga-em-casa.htm